# How do I copy only particular folders but keep the parent folder structure intact?

Tags: perl, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a folder structure:

```
Powershell-build
    Comp1
        Build
        Impl
    Comp2
        Build
        Impl
```

My output folder should contain only the `Build` folder contents like shown below. Actually I want to maintain the parent folder structure but only particular folder contents should be copied.

```
Power-outputbuild
    Comp1
        Build
    Comp2
        Build
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it on perl using `File::Copy::Recursive` module:

```
use File::Copy::Recursive qw/dircopy/;

my $parentdir      = 'Powershell';              # dirname
my $parentdir_copy = $parentdir.'_outputbuild'; # output dirname suffix
opendir(my $dir_handle, $parentdir) 
    or die("Can't open dir: $!");
my @dirs = grep { ! /^\.{1,2}$/ } # ignore parent '..' and current '.' dirs
      readdir($dir_handle) or die("Can't read dir: $!");
for my $dirname (@dirs) {
  my $builddir = $dirname."/Build"; # "Build" directory
  if (-d $parentdir."/".$builddir) {
    dircopy($parentdir."/".$builddir, $parentdir_copy."/".$builddir);
  }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
$source = 'C:\Powershell-build\'
 $target = 'C:\Power-outputbuild\'
 $keep = '\\Build$'

 Get-ChildItem $source |
     where {$_.psiscontainer} |
     select -expand fullname |
     where {$_ -match $keep} |
     foreach {
         $new_dir = $_ -replace [regex]::escape($source),$target
         mkdir $new_dir
         copy-item $_*.* -destination $new_dir
         }
```